# remove part of iso_surface in mayavi

Tags: mayavi

I am trying to find some hints in documentation of mayavi without any success.

In the visualization of complex data I would like to remove a part of computed iso_surface. 
E.g., I have a code like

```
field =  mlab.pipeline.gaussian_splatter(data)
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(field, contours=[0.07])
```

I may remove part of this iso_surface by explicitly explaining that my data is limited along x, y or z by doing something like

```
field.filter.model_bounds = array([-1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1., 1.])
```

But I can not find the way to explain this for an arbitrary directed plane. For instance, I would like to limit my data for a (1,1,1) direction.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data_set_clipper`
 to clip the data. The clipper is either interactive or non interactive. I will demonstrate it for a non interactive version:

```
fld = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data)
clip = mlab.pipeline.data_set_clipper(fld)
clip.widget.widget_mode='ImplicitPlane'
clip.widget.widget.enabled=0
clip.widget.widget.normal=(1,1,1)
clip.widget.widget.origin=(20,20,20) #(0,0,0) is not the centre but the corner
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(clip, contours=[0.07])
```

If you want to clip more often you have to put your clipped data into another `data_set_clippe`:

```
clip2=mlab.pipeline.data_set_clipper(clip)
```

However, I am not fully satisfied with my approach as it uses a lot of resources. If someone has a better solution I would be glad to see it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're having trouble displaying the surface you want, try playing around with the argument of `contours`, if you can make them tight enough around the surface you want to have displayed you should get what you want..

if you could post some more of a {non,}working example I might be able to help out